# Как сохранить данные в переменной в bash скрипте?

Tags: bash, export

Доброго всем дня/вечера

У меня есть скрипт, который использует определенные папки, которые нужно сохранить, чтобы при каждом запуске не вводить заново, или вводить, но только тогда, когда это необходимо.

```
# Сохраняем проект в глобальный массив для использования автоматически

function projectSave() {

    if [ ! -z $PROJECT ]; then 
        echo "Please write a project name!"
        read PROJECTNAME
        export PROJECT=$PROJECTNAME
    else 
        echo "your project is $PROJECT"
    fi 

}

projectSave


exit 1
```

Код выше экспортирует переменную в путь, но там, как я понял, иерархия, и второй раз уже не видно эту переменную. Что делать? Подскажите, кто знает.

Comment: Код выше экспортирует не в путь, а в список переменных. Какая там *иерархия* и что вы хотите дальше? Передать этот путь другому скрипту? Передавайте как параметр.

Comment: Я хочу запустить этот же скрипт, вследующий раз прочитать в другом методе, если она пустая вызвать этот метод

Comment: Всё не так просто. Переменные наследуются сверху вниз, из вашего скрипта они будут доступны только для скриптов, вызванных из вашего скрипта. Если скрипт вызывается потом, из шелла, то и переменную должен экспортировать шелл.

Comment: я не совсем понимаю, что имеется ввиду каждый раз создается новая среда и туда вписывается все переменные которые экспортируются или нужно указывать просто путь до папки или файла где лежит эта переменная. у меня всего один скрипт и одна переменная и я хочу ее использовать N кол-во раз для того, чтобы каждый раз не вводить имя нужного мне проекта.

Comment: Да, при каждом вызове скрипта  создается новая среда, которая является копией  текущей среды и вызываемый скрипт не может изменить среду вызывающего процесса.

Comment: @jcmax: сохраняйте значение в файле, при повторном использовании скрипта, если пользователь ввёл ничто - считывайте вместо этого данные из файла. Ну или как там у вас предполагается всё это организовать...

Answer (score 1):

можно использовать файл для сохранения переменных. и читать из него командой `source`.

---

для вашего примера:

1. добавьте перед вызовом функции `projectSave` например, такую строку:

   ```
   [ -r savedvars ] && source savedvars
   ```
2. а в тексте функции, после получения от пользователя значения переменной, добавьте, например, такую строку:

   ```
   echo "export PROJECT=$PROJECTNAME" > savedvars
   ```

и между вызовами вашей программы значение переменной будет сохраняться в файле `savedvars` в текущем каталоге (как имя, так и месторасположение файла — на полное ваше усмотрение).